# Writing filepaths to a new csv using Python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, for-loop

I'm new to python and trying to create a csv file from a list of files within a folder. Essentially, the code is supposed to write rows based on the files in a folder by parsing the file name to isolate the unique identifier (which here is the name of a city), then writing that identifier to a column, followed by the original file name/file path to the attachment.  This bit of code writes the headers, "City" and "Attachment", then stops and returns the error statement, that no PDFs are in the folder (there are, in fact, 100 PDF files in the folder).

Here is the code that I'm having some trouble editing:

```
attachments_folder = "H:/Attachments"
attachments_table = attachments_folder + "\\" + "attachments_Table.csv"

for f in os.listdir(attachments_folder):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_file, f_city = file_name.split('_')
    writer = csv.writer(open(attachments_table, "wb"), delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["City", "Attachment"])
    if str(f).find(".pdf") > -1:
        writer.writerow([f_city, f])
    else:
        print "Error: no PDF's found"
```

I apologize in advance that this is likely a clunky and/or yucky bit of code. I was curious if I needed to break out the two things going on here (parsing the file name, then write lines to the csv rows), but I got syntax errors with this reformatted version:

```
for f in os.listdir(attachments_folder):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_file, f_city = file_name.split('_')

writer = csv.writer(open(attachments_table, "wb"), delimiter=",")
writer.writerow(["City", "Attachment"])

for f in os.listdir(attachments_folder):
    writer.writerow(["City", "Attachment"])
    if str(f).find(".pdf") > -1:
        writer.writerow([f_city, f])
    else:
        print "Error: no PDF's found"
```

Any guidance on what I'm missing here would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're using inconsistent slashes for your file paths. Try changing the `attachments_folder` to `"H:\\Atachments"`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Gather all pdf files' location in a csv? Right?

Comment: Thanks @arbitrarystringofletters. I actually have this set to be a user defined parameter in a workspace format (within arcpy), and just have that file path as an example. When I print attachments_table, the result is H:\Attachments\attachments_Table.csv with the syntax I have. Everything has been working until I got to the first writer.writerow line.

Comment: What does `os.listdir(attachments_folder)` return?

Comment: @Abhisek Roy Each file includes a city name, preceded by an underscore. I'm trying write a csv file in which each row has the city name, and then the matching file path to a specific pdf document (and the file name of that same pdf is where the city name was taken from).

Comment: @Goyo the os.listdir(attachments_folder) works, and returns the list of pdf files.

Comment: How are you reading data from a pdf @ezihatch11

Comment: @Abhisek Roy the data isn't being read from the pdf. The city name is derived from the name of the pdf file: for example, if the file is "easement1_new york.pdf" then 'easement1' = f_file and 'new york' = f_city  for that pdf.

Comment: Your error message doesn't fit your code. If you have 100 `.pdf` files and 1 `.csv` file (for example) in the target folder, it will print "Error: no PDF's found" because of the last file, even though it did find all 100 PDFs. You should rewrite the error message to something like "Non-PDF file found." You may also consider adding a positive output message that says "PDF file found" when the `if` statement evaluates to `True`. This might help you get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters essentially what happens here is the headers get written to the csv file, then I get that error message. This means that the purpose of the program, to write rows to a csv file, doesn't ever happen. There should be 100 rows, with two columns, city and attachment file: does your comment also imply that because I am writing a .csv file to the target directory, that is essentially stopping the program after those headers, and that's why it only results in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues going on here:

1. Most importantly, you're overwriting the file in each step of the loop, thereby deleting whatever may have been written in prior steps.
2. Secondly, and likely adding to the confusion, your warning isn't telling the truth. One or more PDFs may have been found.

I fixed the first issue by opening the file only once, before the loop. I fixed the second issue by modifying the existing warning and adding another positive status when a PDF is found. Here's a working rewrite of your program (in Python 3):

```
# In Python 3, newline='' prevents extra blank rows. You don't need this in Python 2.
# You can also leave 'wb' as the file mode in Python 2.
with open(attachments_table, 'w', newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(['City', 'Attachment'])

    for f in os.listdir(attachments_folder):
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        f_file, f_city = file_name.split('_')
        if str(f).find('.pdf') > -1:
            print('The current file is a PDF.')
            writer.writerow([f_city, f])
        else:
            print('The current file is not a PDF.')
```

Comment: I see what was messing me up: I was re-opening the csv file with each loop. Thank you! I don't need a confirmation of the file type, but I wanted to have an error message that communicates whether or not there are PDF's in the folder. I think it makes sense to just delete the @arbitrarystringofletters else statement since it is on a file-to-file basis, not on a folder basis. This wrote the files to a csv, but there are gaps every other row, so that's a whole other thing to figure out. I'll let you know if I find a fix there, but thanks again for this solution, this majorly clarifies!

Comment: I figured out the every-other row being written: the mode of the open csv needs to be "wb" instead of "w". Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks-- unfortunately, we're stuck in Python 2 thanks to being limited to ArcGIS for Desktop at the moment.